# Sap HANA xsodata InputParameter value with single quote

Tags: hana, hana-xs

Is there way (except replacing) to pass values with special characters into xsodata InputParameters?

I tried to make request like:

```
../ODATA_SEARCH.xsodata/InputParams(IP_TERM='O'Neal')/Results?$format=json
```

but got an error:

> { "error": { "code": "", "message": { "lang": "en-US", "value": "Syntax error in resource path at position 66."}}}

When I use quotes doubling:

```
ODATA_SEARCH.xsodata/InputParams(IP_TERM='O''NEAL')/Results?$format=json
```

got an error:

> { "error": { "code": "", "message": { "lang": "en-US", "value": "Service exception: [2048] column store error"}}}

But doubling works when I invoke view directly through SQL Script or "Data Preview".

Answer (score 0):

Special characters in URLs can, and sometimes must, be %-encoded like%20this. But for the single quote (`%27`) in the ODATA URI, this will not work:

```
...ms(IP_TERM='O%27Neal')/Results?$for...
```

will still produce a syntax error.

Instead, single quotes in ODATA URIs are escaped by just doubling them. Use it like so:

```
...ms(IP_TERM='O''Neal')/Results?$for...
```

Comment: I tried doubling. It doesn't work. (column store error). But for calc. view execution quotes escaping works fine. Hana version 1.00.85.03.400544

Comment: Can you update the question with the verbatim column store error please?

Comment: ODATA_SEARCH.xsodata/InputParams(IP_TERM='O''NEAL')/Results?$format=json

{ "error": { "code": "", "message": { "lang": "en-US", "value": "Service exception: [2048] column store error"}}}

But it works when I invoke view directly through sql script or "Data Preview".

Answer (score 0):

We decided to pass parameter as base64 string, and than decode it in view:
BASE64_DECODE(:IP_TERM)

Comment: I would suggest you file a ticket with SAP for that.